# How to enable/disable iphone celular network without disable WIFI

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wifi

I'm working on an iPhone app and I'd like to disable phone but keep wifi working. For that i am using the code below:

```
`-(void) disablePhone
{
    void *libHandle = dlopen(”/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony”, RTLD_LAZY);
    int (*enable)(int mode) = dlsym(libHandle, “CTPowerSetAirplaneMode”);
    enable(1);
}


-(void) enablePhone
{
    void *libHandle = dlopen(”/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony”, RTLD_LAZY);
    int (*enable)(int mode) = dlsym(libHandle, “CTPowerSetAirplaneMode”);
    enable(0);
}`
```

But it is getting crashed at `enable(1)` and `enable(0)` lines.
Can anybody help me why its getting crashed?

or

is there any other solution through which I can change the mode of iphone to flight mode  without disable wifi.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Interesting. Is it acceptable by Apple iPhone App Approval process?

Answer (score -1):

Due to the sandboxing of iOS apps, I would doubt this is acceptable to Apple. I would instruct the user to do it manually; it seems like the only way.  They can turn off the cellular network in settings without turning on airplane mode.